# Problem in writing the equation: missing delimiter (.inserted)

Tags: math-mode, equations

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{...} %packages your code nees

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
T\triangleq &\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\gamma^{k+m_2-1}{\rm exp}\Big(-\frac{m_2\gamma}{\bar\gamma_2}\Big)}{\Big1+(\frac{(m_1+s\bar\gamma_1)\gamma}{cm_1}\Big)^{m_1}(1+\frac{1}{c}\gamma_2)^{\lceil m_1 \rceil -m_1}}{\rm d}\gamma.\\
\nonumber
=&C\int_{0}^{\infty}\gamma^{k+m_2-1}{\rm exp}\Bigg(-\frac{m_2\gamma}{\bar\gamma_2}\Bigg)\\
&\texttimes H_{1,1}^{1,1} \left[\begin{gathered} \frac{(m_1+s\bar\gamma_1)\gamma}{cm_1}\end{gathered}\left\vert \begin{gathered} (1-m_1,1) \\ (0,1)\end{gathered}\right.\right]H_{1,1}^{1,1} \left[\begin{gathered} \frac{\gamma}{c}\end{gathered}\left\vert \begin{gathered} (1-\lceil m_1 \rceil +m_1,1) \\ (0,1)\end{gathered}\right.\right]{\rm d}\gamma\\
=&C\Bigg(\frac{\bar\gamma_2}{m_2}\Bigg)^{k+m_2}H_{1,\,[1:\,1],\,0,\,[1:\,1]}^{1,\,1,\,1,\,1,\,1} \left[\begin{gathered}
\frac{(m_1+s\bar{\gamma}_{_1})\bar{\gamma}_{_2}}{c\,m_1m_2} \\ \frac{\bar{\gamma}_{_2}}{c\,m_2}\end{gathered}
\left\vert \begin{gathered} (k+m_2,1) \\ (1-m_1,1);(1-\lceil{m_1}\rceil+m_1,) \\ - \\ (0,1);(0,1)
\end{gathered}\right.\right].\\
=&C\Bigg(\frac{\bar\gamma_2}{m_2}\Bigg)^{k+m_2}G_{1,\,[1:\,1],\,0,\,[1:\,1]}^{1,\,1,\,1,\,1,\,1}\left[\begin{gathered}\frac{(m_1+s\bar{\gamma}_{_1})\bar{\gamma}_{_2}}{c\,m_1m_2}\\\frac{\bar{\gamma}_{_2}}{c\,m_2}\end{gathered}\left\vert \begin{gathered} k+m_2\\1-m_1;1-\lceil{m_1}\rceil+m_1 \\ - \\ 0;0\end{gathered}\right.\right].
 \end{align}

\end{document}
```

I have successfully generated the equation in the picture, but after compiling LaTeX always showed that `Missing delimiter (.inserted). \end{align}` What's the solution?

Comment: a ![enter image description here][1] crept into the last line and perhaps you could add a preamble and postamble so your example is a complete document?

Comment: `\Big1` is wrong; you probably meant `1+\Big(`; however it should be `\Bigl(` and `\Bigr)` throughout. Also `{\rm exp}` is wrong and it should be `\exp`, and `{\rm d}` should be `\mathrm{d}`.

Comment: Also, you should use `&=` not `=&`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input

```
\Big1+(
```

should be

```
1+\Bigl(
```

Also the other `\Big` tokens should be changed: use `\Bigl` in front of an opening delimiter and `\Bigr` in front of a closing delimiter. Similarly for `\Bigg`, which should be either `\Biggl` or `\Biggr`.

Use `\exp`, not `{\rm exp}` and `\,\mathrm{d}` in place of `{\rm d}`. The `\rm` command has been deprecated for 20 years.

If you want the alignment point after the `=` (or `\triangleeq`), then use `={}&` or the spacing will be wrong.

The command `\texttimes` is wrong, it should be `\times`.

Instead of the clumsy

```
\left[ <...> \left| <...> \right.\right]
```

construct, you can use

```
\left[ <...> \;\middle|\; <...> \right]
```

Final point to note: you have several `\gamma_{_1}` or similar, which are wrong: if you want to lower the subscript, type

```
\gamma^{}_{1}
```

Here's a fixed version

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} %packages your code nees

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
T\triangleq{} &
  \int_{0}^{\infty}
  \frac
    {\gamma^{k+m_2-1}\exp\Bigl(-\frac{m_2\gamma}{\bar\gamma_2}\Bigr)}
    {1+\Bigl(\frac{(m_1+s\bar\gamma_1)\gamma}{cm_1}\Bigr)^{m_1}(1+\frac{1}{c}\gamma_2)
      ^{\lceil m_1 \rceil -m_1}}
  \,\mathrm{d}\gamma
\\
\nonumber
={}& C\int_{0}^{\infty}\gamma^{k+m_2-1}\exp\Biggl(-\frac{m_2\gamma}{\bar\gamma_2}\Biggr)
\\
&\times H_{1,1}^{1,1}
  \left[
    \frac{(m_1+s\bar\gamma_1)\gamma}{cm_1}
  \;\middle|\;
    \begin{gathered} (1-m_1,1) \\ (0,1)\end{gathered}
  \right]
  H_{1,1}^{1,1}
  \left[
    \frac{\gamma}{c}
  \;\middle|\;
    t \begin{gathered} (1-\lceil m_1 \rceil +m_1,1) \\ (0,1)\end{gathered}
  \right]
  \mathrm{d}\gamma
\\
={}& C\Biggl(\frac{\bar\gamma_2}{m_2}\Biggr)^{k+m_2}
  H_{1,\,[1:\,1],\,0,\,[1:\,1]}^{1,\,1,\,1,\,1,\,1}
  \left[
    \begin{gathered}
    \frac{(m_1+s\bar{\gamma}^{}_{1})\bar{\gamma}^{}_{2}}{c\,m_1m_2} \\
    \frac{\bar{\gamma}^{}_{2}}{c\,m_2}
    \end{gathered}
  \;\middle|\;
    \begin{gathered}
    (k+m_2,1) \\
    (1-m_1,1);(1-\lceil{m_1}\rceil+m_1,) \\
     - \\
    (0,1);(0,1)
    \end{gathered}
  \right]
\\
={}& C\Biggl(\frac{\bar\gamma_2}{m_2}\Biggr)^{k+m_2}
  G_{1,\,[1:\,1],\,0,\,[1:\,1]}^{1,\,1,\,1,\,1,\,1}
  \left[
    \begin{gathered}
    \frac{(m_1+s\bar{\gamma}^{}_{1})\bar{\gamma}^{}_{2}}{c\,m_1m_2}\\
    \frac{\bar{\gamma}_{_2}}{c\,m_2}
    \end{gathered}
  \;\middle|\;
    \begin{gathered}
    k+m_2\\1-m_1;1-\lceil{m_1}\rceil+m_1 \\
    - \\
    0;0\end{gathered}
  \right].
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Sigur I'll fix it immediately.

Comment: The reason to use `={}&` instead of the classical `&=` is due to `\times`?

Comment: Thank you soooooo much for the detailed solution! I am still a green hand on this and also try hard to read The LaTeX Companion these days, so I don't understand lots of the grammar and expression clearly yet. And yet I got another problem: If I want to generate this equation using \begin{eqnarray} and \end{eqnarry}, what's the difference? And which method is more acceptable?

Comment: And indeed I am using \IEEEtran so that the article has two columns. But the equation above is so long and large that I have to use \onecolumn to make it display in the middle of the paper, however I was told that the format doesn't fit the requirements. So my question is how can I put the long equation above in just the half of the paper?

Comment: @VinntonYao Sorry, you can't. Use shorthands.

Comment: @egreg To be more detailed?